# ¿Qué es exactamente un algoritmo y diagrama de flujo?

Tags: algoritmos

¿Qué es un algoritmo? He visto que es una serie de pasos a seguir, pero lo que me confunde es que le llamen algoritmo a un código y a unos pasos, por ejemplo:

```
for(byte i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Lo anterior he visto que lo llaman también algoritmo, y a lo otro que le llaman algoritmo es a esto:

(Algoritmo de tomar agua)

1. Iniciar algoritmo
2. Dirigirse a la botella de agua
3. Tomar la botella de agua
4. Destapar la botella de agua
5. Acercar la botella a la boca
6. Empezar a beber

Y según mi maestro, lo anterior está bien. Si pudieran darme un ejemplo de uno avanzado, lo agradecería bastante.

Respecto al diagrama de flujo, ¿para qué es exactamente? no sé cómo lo podría usar si estoy en desarrollo de aplicaciones de Windows.

Comment: 1) Un lenguaje es una herramienta que nos permita expresar "algo".  Podemos decir "Rojo" en español o "Red" en inglés, pero ese "algo" es lo mismo. 2) Un algoritmo son una serie de pasos para lograr un resultado (un receta de cocina es un algoritmo), entonces: 3) Tú tienes un código, un lista y un diagrama de flujo de algo, los 3 pueden considerarse un algoritmo pero escritos en lenguajes diferentes.

Comment: ahhh, ya veo. Creí que eran cosas distintas, pero parece que es lo mismo en ese caso

Comment: Un diagrama es un lenguaje, nos sirve para expresar ideas gráficamente, algo que en palabras sería demasiado largo de explicar. Luego está la estandarización de los diagramas, porque cualquiera puede hacer un dibujo, pero la idea que otra persona lo entienda, por eso es bueno que tengan reglas y forma (como la RAE para el español). El diagrama de flujo es muy usado en el desarrollo de SW desde mostrar el funcionamiento de un algoritmo (en lo micro) hasta el funcionamiento del sistema entero (en lo macro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un algoritmo, tanto en matemáticas como ciencias de la computación es un conjunto de instrucciones o reglas definidas y no-ambiguas (usando el término en su máxima definición heredada de las matemáticas y estructuras discretas), ordenadas y finitas que permite, grosso modo, solucionar un problema; dado un estado inicial y una entrada, siguiendo los pasos sucesivos se llega a un estado final y se obtiene una solución.

Rebajando el tono de la descripción, tanto los pasos que realizas para beber agua, solucionar una ecuación o aplicar una solución software son algoritmos, normalmente.

Un diagrama de flujo representa de forma gráfica este algoritmo para que sea posteriormente fácilmente entendible, escalable y compartible con otros.

Por poner un ejemplo, he hecho un diagrama del "algoritmo de la botella de agua", de forma que comprendas el uso. Me he tomado la libertad de añadirle una condición para que sea más didáctico (y el algoritmo tenga más sentido finalista).

[image: Diagrama de flujo]

Post-data: siendo quisquillosos, el código no es un algoritmo como tal; sino el código que materializa el algoritmo (que repito, es una construcción abstracta).

```
for(byte i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Así,el algoritmo representado por un diagrama de flujo del código sería:

[image: Diagrama de flujo de ejemplo]

Comment: Ahora sí comprendí esto, me parece que es muy útil. Aunque no sé si aplico bien los algoritmos como por ejemplo, el de tomar agua

Comment: He editado la respuesta con un ejemplo de diagrama de flujo con el algoritmo de la botella de agua. Como ves, efectivamente se trata de un algoritmo a nivel teórico (otra cosa es que tenga una aplicación matemática o de programación, que no lo tiene). Pero creo que de forma didáctica entenderás bien con este ejemplo gráfico; a la vez que comprendes mejor el por qué del uso de diagramas de flujo.

Answer (score 0):

Un algoritmo es un **conjunto de instrucciones** para lograr un fin.

El código son instrucciones, así que puede representar un algoritmo.

Un diagrama de flujo es una manera gráfica y sencilla de representar un algoritmo.

Ahora imagina (como programador):

- Tienes un fin, piensas los pasos a seguir para lograrlo, ya estarías creando tu algoritmo.
- Ahora creas un diagrama de flujo para representarlo y pulirlo.
- Finalmente, escribes el código para implementar ese algoritmo.

Obviamente, hay casos en que te puedes saltar el diagrama de flujo e ir directamente al código. Pero cuando existe cierta complejidad en la tarea a realizar, pensar un poco y dibujar el diagrama ayudará bastante.